# hint.css manual line break in hint

Tags: html, css, line-breaks, hint

How can I apply manual line breaks in [Hint.css](http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/) hints?

I tried almost everything: `<br>, \n,` and combinations of them.

I tried also some things in the CSS:

```
white-space: normal;
word-wrap: break-word;
word-wrap: no-wrap;
word-wrap:break-word
white-space: nowrap;
```

**Now**: Without line break, the hint is one line high, but and any length long.

**Ideally**: Apply a manual line break wherever I want, leaving the untouched hints without line breaks.

Comment: It's a bit hard to interpret your question and your desired outcome. Please provide minimal code necessary to demonstrate your problem, and if possible, an example (e.g., screenshot or separate markup/CSS code that produces the same outcome) of the desired behavior.

Comment: What is hint.css? The tag has no definition, and it has 0 followers.

Comment: http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer at:

https://github.com/chinchang/hint.css/issues/24

In action:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/gVPty/][2]
```

Comment: The linked answer says to include `&#10;` in the text.  But if setting from jQuery, which strips out the ampersand code, use `\u000A`

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this today and came across this answer so I'm posting my solution:

I needed the tooltip to automatically break the line - because some tooltips I couldn't control the content. So the solution was adding the "line-breaker" properties to the tooltip element:

```

```css
[class*=hint--]:after {
    min-width: 300px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

```

The `min-width` is set so when you have a string like "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" it doesn't break all the the "a"s into new lines without considering a min-width. Here is an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/CfTCxaqPxd1K2Jx5P7nc

Answer (score 1):

Im using v2.3.1 and had to add this CSS to make the line breaks work:

```
[class*=hint--][aria-label]:after {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

Im using `&#10;` as the line break character.