# hint.css expand tooltip height with content

Tags: html, css

I am using [HINT.css](http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/) for tool-tipping, and I can't for the love of god get the tooltip to expand with the content. I've tried clear fixing, setting heights and what not, but to no avail. Basically I would like to be able to say:

```
&:after
        content: attr(data-hint)
        background: $defaultColor
        color: white
        padding: $verticalPadding $horizontalPadding
        font-size: $fontSize
        line-height: $fontSize // Vertical centering.
        width: 150px
        min-height: 10px
```

and then the div will just expand along with the content (basically trying to prevent out-of-bounds cases)

```
<div class="hint" data-hint="Some very very very very very long tooltip going past 150px and should be multilined"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue which was related to very domain specific code that interlaced with the way hint.css is structured. I had to rewrite hint.css to a custom solution to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS file of the plugin, add the following two CSS properties to .hint  class after pseudo element.

```
.hint:after
{
    width: 150px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: That is not doing the trick. I can do some shenanigans with the

hint:after { display: block; position: relative; } but that fubars the positioning of the body to the arrow

Comment: May be you could show us a demo of your issue? Also see this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24310180/hint-css-manual-line-break-in-hint

Answer (score 0):

You have set a fixed width of 150px. Try using no width or if you need a minimum, use min-width.